# SQLCount with join query

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am using angularjs.I am trying to display count by using join query.I have three tables.Its structures are given below

fundraisers

```
    fundraiserId  
     1
```

fundraisingusers

```
    fundraisinguserId  userId fundraiserId
        1                  1         1
```

users

```
        userId //and other columns 
           1
```

Now i am writing query something like this

```
SELECT f.fundraiserId 
     , fu.userId 
  FROM fundraisers f 
  LEFT 
  JOIN fundraisingusers fu 
    ON f.fundraiserId = fu.fundraiserId 
  LEFT 
  JOIN users u 
    ON fu.userId = u.userId;
```

Now in front html i want to display count of users that is the number of users present in fundraisingusers table.In this case 1.But now i dont know how to get count in a join query.At present i am getting userId.I need to display it as count not as Id.

Here is my html

```
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4" data-ng-repeat="fundraise
    in fundraises">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>Supporters
    <h6>{{fundraise.userId}}</h6>//Here i need count of users from fundraisingusers table but i am getting userId
    </div>
```

Here is the POJO class which i am using to display the data

```
    public class Fundraisers implements Serializable{
    private Integer fundraiserId;
    private Integer userId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "fundraiserId")
    public Integer getFundraiserId() {
    return fundraiserId;
    }
    public void setFundraiserId(Integer fundraiserId) {
    this.fundraiserId = fundraiserId;
    }

    @Transient
    @JoinColumn(insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
    }
```

Here is my database access dao code

```
    @Override
    public List<Fundraisers> getFundsByIndexWithStatusForFront() 
    {
      List<Fundraisers> fundRaisers = new ArrayList<Fundraisers>();
      Query query = 
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(FUNDRAISES);//Here i am using above query
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Fundraisers.class));
        fundRaisers = query.list();
        return fundRaisers;
     }
```

Can anyone tell how can i get count of userId and not userId?

Comment: There is absolutely no point outer joining a table from which you select no columns.

Comment: I have other columns.But for posting purpose i thought those are not necessary

Answer (score -1):

Try it doing a GROUP BY and use count():

```
SELECT f.fundraiserId as fundraiserId,
       CAST(count(fu.userId) AS CHAR) as userId 
FROM fundraisers as f 
     left outer join fundraisingusers as fu on f.fundraiserId =fu.fundraiserId 
     left outer join users as u on fu.userId = u.userId
group by f.fundraiserId;
```

Comment: I have updated my question.I am using pojo for displaying data.If i use count in the query it is throwing error as argument type mismatch

Comment: @Sachin HR You can CAST your data as string. I have edited my answer

Comment: Do i need to change type of userId as String in pojo class?

Comment: What is your pojo class type, where you need to get the count value?

Comment: userId is Integer in pojo

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT f.fundraiserId as fundraiserId,COUNT(fu.userId) as userId 
FROM
fundraisers f 
left outer join fundraisingusers fu on
f.fundraiserId = fu.fundraiserId 
left outer join users u on fu.userId = u.userId";
```

Comment: I have updated my question.I am using pojo for displaying data.If i use count in the query it is throwing error as argument type mismatch

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT COUNT(fu.userId) as userId ,
```

this function returns number of Users .
right query :

```
SELECT f.fundraiserId as fundraiserId,COUNT(fu.userId) as userId FROM
fundraisers as f left outer join fundraisingusers as fu on
f.fundraiserId = fu.fundraiserId left outer join users as u on
fu.userId = u.userId";
```

Comment: I have updated my question.I am using pojo for displaying data.If i use count in the query  it is throwing error as argument type mismatch

Comment: you POJO ist wrong because you haft to create a relation many to many to User Entity because will get the list of users ,, in this way u can count this list and take number of users ,, are u Using Hibernate ?

Comment: Yes. I am using hibernate

Comment: in this situation you can configure the many to many relationship between "fundraisers " and "users " using "fundraisingusers " ,  from FUNDRAISERS   we get a list of Fundraisingusers which have a user object inside , i this way we cant this list where user id its not null ,, here is a link to do this configuration , --- https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/